# Python: How to append to existing key of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary with multidimensional lists, like so:

```
myDict = {'games':[ ['Post 1', 'Post 1 description'], ['Post2, 'desc2'] ], 'fiction':[ ['fic post1', 'p 1 fiction desc'], ['fic post2, 'p 2 fiction desc'] ]}
```

How would I add a new list with ['Post 3', 'post 3 description'] to the games key list?

Comment: Just use `append` with an indexing!

Answer (score 7):

You're appending to the value (which is a list in this case), not the key.

```
myDict['games'].append(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myDict["games"].append(['Post 3', 'post 3 description'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append value to existing key is to use append() method of list.

```
dict[key].append(value)
dict[key].extend(list of values)
```

In your case you can write like this

myDict['games'].append(['Post 3', 'post 3 description'])

## the above statement will add argument as a one value

myDict['games'].extend(['Post 3', 'post 3 description'])

## the above statement will add 'Post3' and 'post 3 description' as an individual argument to myDict['games']

Answer (score 0):

Use the **append()** operation of a list.

```
myDict['games'].append(['Post 3', 'post 3 description'])
```

First you need to access the `'games'` key of the dictionary using the `dict[key]` lookup which is a list. Then value you obtain on `games` key lookup is a list.
Then use the `append()` operation to add `['Post 3', 'post 3 description']` it to the list inside `games` key.